# websocket + vuejs: screen flickering, visible mustache code

Tags: javascript, websocket, vue.js

I built a web-app using websockets, and vuejs.

In the DOM I want to loop over the data handled by vuejs. The data however is set later in the timeline, after a websocket connection has been established and the data has been received.

Up to that point (about 0.5 seconds), you can see the mustache code for vuejs on the site itself, then see it flicker and adding the real data.

I create the **ViewModel**, when receiving data from the websocket connection, like this:

```
onMessage: function (e) {
    new Vue({
        el: '#messages',
        data: {
            messages: e.data
        }
    });
}
```

What I already tried was initializing the ViewModels on page load, and set the data later:

```
var vms = {
    messages: new Vue({
        el: '#messages',
        data: {
            messages: {
            }
        }
    })
};
```

In the `onMessage` event of the websocket:

```
var vm = vms.messages;
vm.$data = { messages: body };
```

The problem is though, that there is still a delay, until the the vm is intialized. The sequence is like this:

page load -> visible mustache code -> mustache code is hidden, because data is set to an empty object -> real data is shown after it's received by the websocket

Any ideas / best practices on that matter?

Comment: use mustache to set a classname, hide all but that classname in CSS. the CSS won't hit the un-interpolated placeholder, and when it turns into a real css class, it will stop being hidden.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the same problem until I read the api doc.
Here is the link for [v-cloak directives](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak)!

HTML:

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak><p>{{ test }}</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
[v-cloak] {display: none}
```

Comment: Sorry,I didn't notice that jel has already posted the correct solution:)

Comment: Haven't encountered this problem, but wouldn't it be a pretty universal expectation that mustache tags always remain invisible? If so, why wouldn't `v-cloak` be the default? I know this answer is from 1+ years ago but just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on dandavis' comment, I added a "hidden" class (`display: none`) to the DOM, and `v-class="hidden: !done"`, to toggle the visibility of the DOM. `done` is a key-value pair in the data of the ViewModel.

HTML:

```
<div class="message hidden" v-repeat="messages" v-class="hidden: !done">...</div>
```

Javascript:

```
onMessage: function (e) {
    new Vue({
        el: '#messages',
        data: {
            messages: e.data,
            done: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: not sure if would overwrite the hidden css class. A better solution would be to use v-cloak (with display: none), and v-show="done", instead of toggling the css class.

Comment: After fiddling with v-show I settled on v-cloak instead. First set a rule of [v-cloak] { display: none } in your css. Then add v-cloak to any element you want hidden until the vm is loaded. http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-cloak